# How to show ManyToMany fields using CreateView in Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-1.8

I'm doing a basic application in Django 1.8 and I'm using Create-View, I don't know why the create form doesn't have manyTOmany fields neither foreign-key field previously defined in my model. This is my code:

> My Model:

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ....
class Editor(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
class Libro(models.Model):
   titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   autores = models.ManyToManyField(Autor) #MANY2MANY FIELD
   editor = models.ForeignKey(Editor) #FOREIGN KEY FIELD
   fecha_publicacion = models.DateField()
   portada = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'portadas/')

   def __unicode__(self):
    return self.titulo
```

> My View:

```
class LibroCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Libro
   template_name = 'biblioteca/crear.html'
   fields = ['titulo', 'autores', 'editor', 'fecha_publicacion', 'portada']
```

> My template:

```
{% block main %}
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{form.as_table}}   
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="crear" value="Crear">
</form> <br>
{% endblock main %}
```

> My result
>   [image]

Why isn't my fields "Autores"(many2many) and "Editor"(foreign-key) correctly shown?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving form to the view that is `CreateView`. Make a `ModelForm` using your model

There you can do query for you foreign key and many to many field.
You can present them as you like

Comment: Of course, I've my ModelForm but still both, My Many-to-many and foreign-key fields, don't working. Here I show you a my code's image...however, if I solve it, I will post my solution. https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8607266/9178906/c0c49920-3f5e-11e5-9717-1baf77dad654.png

Comment: Your code here and code in screen shot are different. Use create view and it will just save the model according to your form. simple..